# Get jpg from UDP hex dump with wireshark

Tags: hex, jpeg, wireshark, hexdump

I am trying to take part in a CTF challenge. I have a pcap file of a jpg file transfer. I know that the jpg starts with `FF D8 FF` and ends with `FF D9`.

The problem is that I have no idea how to extract the file itself.

The file is in here:

```
00000226  67 0d 0a 0d 0a ff d8 ff  e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00   g....... ...JFIF.
00000236  01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00  00 ff db 00 43 00 03 02   ........ ....C...
..
00015617  d2 51 95 15 f7 e1 c0 d8  e9 6d 58 c8 07 71 c7 40   .Q...... .mX..q.@
00015627  3a 79 53 19 33 54 00 05  b4 92 07 33 5e af 54 2d   :yS.3T.. ...3^.T-
00015637  1f ff d9                                           ...
```

As you can see it's mixed with `67 0d 0a 0d` and the other information. I tried to copy the relevant parts and cut out the offset and ascii (?) section left and right with python and then imported the hexdump to [this site](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_file.php?lang=en) to create a jpg of the hex dump.

Unfortunately that didn't work. The resulting image is extremely distorted and I can't read anything on it.

Does anyone have an advice? Not a full solution, just a tip so I can wrap my head around it myself.
Thanks.

Comment: What protocol was used to transport the image?  Was it http, ftp, ...?

Comment: `xxd -r` is good for reconstruction of original data from hex dumps, btw.